# Is this TV mounted safely?

Tags: safety, television

I'm not worried about the connection between the mount and the wall - I do know how to do that properly. I'm worried, in this case, about the connection between the TV and the mount - specifically, in this case, a 65" TCL 65R617 TV with a Sanus VLT6 mount.

The wall mount came with spacers to use in case the back of the TV isn't flat, which as you can see in the first attached picture were necessary. Specifically, I used 7mm worth of spacers. (The screw holes on the TV are quite shallow, and the margin between a too-short screw and a too-long one is only a few mm. None of the screws that came with the mount were the right size, but I found something at my local hardware store that works as long as I add a couple of extra washers.)

My concern is this: The full weight and pressure of the mount/tv connection is not against the sturdy metal inner frame of the TV, or distributed evenly across the back of the TV, but rather focused on a small amount of rather flimsy-looking plastic around the screw hole. You can see what I'm talking about in the pictures. It feels like if I tighten the screws too much, I'll crush the TV's plastic frame. And as soon as I hang the TV, its full weight will be on those four small weak points. Is this really secure, and is it how this TV is meant to be mounted?

The gap, requiring the use of 7mm spacers:
[image: 1]

The plastic spacers against the plastic frame of the TV - a weak point?
[image: 2]

Comment: It isn't clear from the pictures why you can't eliminate the spacers and use shorter screws (or cut longer screws to the proper length).  The top picture looks like the TV has a bump-out at the bottom, but that you could still mount through the slot with the TV lower so the bracket is flat against the back.  Have you considered mounting a piece of plywood to the TV using the threaded holes and then fastening the plywood to the bracket?

Comment: @fixer1234 This mount, like many others, has a slot for the bottom screw but discrete holes for the top screw. If I move the top screw to the next hole, then the slot no longer reaches the lower screw hole.

Comment: Can you drill a new hole in the mount?

Comment: did you follow manufacturer directions?

Comment: `back of the TV isn't flat, which as you can see in the first attached picture` ... no, you cannot see that

Comment: @Bryce no, the holes are already far too close together. There's only a few mm of clearance at the bottom - *no* mount will work unless the holes happen to line up perfectly.

Comment: @jsotola which manufacturer? I followed both the (excellent) instructions that came with the mount, and also the (very minimal) instructions available for the TV. Also - look closer at that picture. Just below the screw hole, the plastic frame of the TV juts out 6mm. If I move the mount up so that it can lay flush against the back of the TV, then the slot no longer reaches far enough down to reach the screw hole.

Comment: @Bryce (I suppose one could technically drill the slot to make it a little longer, but I don't have the sort of tools I'd need to drill through the fairly heavy metal that the mount is made of.)

Comment: @jsotola The TV came with no mounting hardware, other than 4 screws too short to be useful with any mount. The mount came with lots of hardware, all depicted in the [manual](https://www.sanus.com/assets/products/vlt6/documents/VLT6_901_002612.pdf). See in particular the right side of page 7, "Determine spacer need." My setup looks kind of like picture (b), except the spacer is pressed against the plastic case of the TV instead of metal. The insets for the screw holes are much smaller than the spacers that came with the mount. Maybe I could go out again and try to find smaller spacers?

Comment: look at this ... https://www.amazon.com/SES-CO-Bracket-Washers-Spacers-Samsung/dp/B01MF4ML9L ........ do you have anything like the black tubular spacers? ..... those fit inside the recessed hole on the TV where the mounting nuts are .... you need to use those so that the pressure is against the nut and not against the outside of the cabinet

Comment: @jsotola those might fit in the hole, but they'd still be resting on plastic. The problem, though it's hard to tell from my picture, is that inside the hole the plastic flattens out again and then has an even smaller hole just large enough for the screw, with very little clearance around it.

Comment: `they'd still be resting on plastic` ... no, the plastic would be sandwiched between the spacer and the metal chassis underneath .... i am sure that the design engineers did their homework

Comment: Basically, the plastic is designed to create a space where it is needed. Personally, because of the TV design in play here, I would simply use a metal washer to keep the mounts off the back of the TV. Here is some decent information. https://www.avforums.com/threads/wall-mount-are-you-supposed-to-use-spacers.1012887/

Comment: That cardboard is just so much NOT a solution. I am surprised you even had the gall to post a picture of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it is meant to be mounted.

The plastic cabinet does not support any weight.

If you put a large washer, or cardboard over the plastic cabinet without using a spacer, then you run a chance of crushing the plastic of the cabinet when you tighten the bolts.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic picture to get the proper point across.

Comment: That's definitely how I'd like to mount it. Unfortunately, neither the TV nor the mount came with an appropriate spacer. My local hardware store doesn't have anything appropriate, either. It's absolutely bizarre to me that the TV manufacturer would require such a precisely shaped spacer, and then not include it with the TV. Any thoughts on how to best find such a spacer?

Comment: Thank you for that great picture! You just answered a question I’ve been struggling with for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, of sorts: I made my own spacers out of cardboard. Definitely not the intended way to install a mount like this, but it's stable and secure, and distributes the pressure across a much larger area. And, most importantly, it's hidden behind the TV where nobody can see it :)

[image: A solution]

Comment: i think that you misunderstand where the pressure points and stress points are

Comment: Not sure what you think the cardboard will do, but this is a bad idea.  The cardboard will just crush.  You want the intended spacers at the screws.  The TV mounts are designed to do the job when used as intended.

Comment: The screw holes are shallower than the 12mm required by the VESA standard. They are not centered on the TV, but are offset only 4 inches from the bottom of the TV, making it hard to hide the mount; and there's a 6mm ridge an inch from the screw holes, preventing the use of most mounts without adding a spacer. In addition, the TV comes with screws that are too short for use with *any* mount, with or without a spacer. Nothing about this is well-engineered - mounting seems to have been an afterthought.

Comment: @fixer1234, I pre-crushed the cardboard to get the appropriate thickness. It's ugly, but it should be safe. See my next comment for a proposed alternative solution.

Comment: @jsotola and others - what do you suppose would happen if I used no spacers, but added a nut on the screw between the TV and the mount, tightened against the mount? That would enforce a gap between the mount and the TV without touching the pastic at all. So, just to be clear, you'd have: screw head > washer > mounting bracket > washer > nut > ...gap... > tv. That should work, without any metal-against-plastic to worry about at all - right?

Comment: You're trying to solve a problem that isn't there, and are likely to create a problem in the process.  Use the TV and bracket hardware as the instruction show.  If the TV mounting holes aren't centered, that's intentional.  It reflects the center of the weight, and that is where strength was built-in for mounting.  The VESA standard allows the manufacturers to deviate.  Spacers, and metal on plastic, aren't a problem.  If you're concerned that the bracket isn't a good fit, get a different bracket.  Or mount strips or a square of plywood to the TV and mount the plywood to the bracket.